# How does Suzume enter the ever after using the door near the ruins of her house, and return back?

Tags: plot-explanation, suzume

In the movie [Suzume](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt16428256/), we are told in the beginning of the movie that living people can't enter the "ever-after" which is shown when certain doors are opened. However, Suzume is able to jump into the ever after via a door near the ruins of her house (image below). I remember something is told about Suzume being able to see the ever after because of some childhood incident. [This](https://fugitives.com/suzume-ending-explained-2023-anime-adventure-film-makoto-shinkai/) site mentions:

> There is only one door that she can use to cross into the land of the
> souls, and that is the one she went through while searching for her
> mother. Because little Suzume had wandered off into the “ever-after,”
> she was able to see the worms and help Souta.

But there's no real explanation about how she's able to jump into the ever after even though she isn't dead, and how she manages to return back. Is there any explanation about it?

[image]